# Wiktionary API call get specific data on page

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, wiktionary

I am looking to make a call to the wiktionary API (the Russian one in specific) and I would like to try and get particular pieces of information on the page. In my case, I would like to target the table on the right, [here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) right above the picture of the map.

I can use any form of the url to get the data, I just am not sure how to target that particular element.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible (at this moment) to get a declension table by using the Wiktionary API.

Comment: Thanks. That is really too bad, as the table must be dynamically generate.